# Laravel 2 construct in trait collide

Tags: php, laravel, traits, collision

I'm using 2 trait, each trait has it own construct method, but when 2 trait is import in same controller, the construct method create collisions.

Trait one
`<?php
namespace App\Traits;
...

trait TraitOne
{
private $apiUrl;
...

```
public function __construct()
{
    ...
}`
```

Trait two
`<?php
namespace App\Traits;

...

trait TraitTwo
{
public $NEW_PASSWORD_CHALLENGE = 'NEW_PASSWORD_REQUIRED';
...

```
private $key;
...

public function __construct()
{
    ...
}`
```

Controller
`<?php
namespace App\Http\Controllers;
...
use App\Traits\TraitOne;
use App\Traits\TraitTwo;
...

class UserAuthController extends Controller
{
use TraitOne, TraitTwo;

```
public function createUser(Request $request)
{
    // calling trait one methods
    $checkUser = $this->createLead($request);

    // calling trait two methods
    $checkUser = $this->getUser($request->email);
}
```

}`

I'm having error like
`Trait method __construct has not been applied, because there are collisions with other trait methods on App\Http\Controllers\UserAuthController`

Both construct method is important, how can I use 2 trait at the same time?

I have no idea what should I do next.

Comment: I am not clear on what exactly do you want, but what I can understand from the problem is that both traits have the constructor defined, while invocation the controller needs to be instructed to pick constructor from either of the two.

Answer (score 1):

You could alias the trait constructor methods:

Import either one of the trait as(Considering the `TraitOne` to be aliased).

```
use TraitOne{
   TraitOne::__construct as constructorOne
};
```

Now you could easily use it within your constructor as:

```
$this->constructorOne();
```

More info here: https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.traits.php